# default tree node expanded in p:tree not working

Tags: jsf, primefaces

By default tree node expanded in PrimeFaces not working.
Here is XHTML:

```
<p:tree value="#{marketMappinBean.root}" 
        selectionMode="checkbox"
        selection="#{marketMappinBean.selectedNode}"
        var="node" id="treeNode"  animate="true" highlight="true" style="width: auto "
>

<p:treeNode>
    <h:outputText value="#{node.name}" />
</p:treeNode>
```

Here is java class code:

```
root = db.getSelectedEmployeeMarketsTree(userID);
root.setExpanded(true);
```

I want that when I click on the button by default tree node should be expanded. and it is showing on next page,until now it is showing on next page but not expanded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be expanded, the `setExpanded` should be applied to the node and not to the root:

> TreeNode node = new DefaultTreeNode("Text", root);
>
> node.setExpanded(true);